# Issue at teardown with Jest + mongodb-memory-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jestjs

I'm trying to run a typescript + jest + mongodb-memory-server test environment but I'm getting the following error at teardown:

```
events.js:189
    throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({ MongoNetworkError: read ECONNRESET
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Plataforma\Estrutura\Final\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:321:24)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} })
    at Connection.emit (events.js:187:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Plataforma\Estrutura\Final\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:321:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Here are my config files:

Jest config:

```
//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  globalSetup: './setup',
  globalTeardown: './teardown.js',
  testEnvironment: './mongo-environment.js',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  roots: ['<rootDir>/test'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'json', 'node'],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
};
```

Here's the setup config

```
//setup.js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const MongodbMemoryServer = require('mongodb-memory-server');

const globalConfigPath = path.join(__dirname, 'globalConfig.json');

const mongod = new MongodbMemoryServer.default({
    instance: {
        dbName: 'StructureGenerator',
        debug: true,
    },
    binary: {
        version: '3.2.18',
    }
});

module.exports = async function () {
    const mongoConfig = {
        mongoDBName: 'StructureGenerator',
        mongoUri: await mongod.getConnectionString(),
    };

    // Write global config to disk because all tests run in different contexts.
    fs.writeFileSync(globalConfigPath, JSON.stringify(mongoConfig));
    console.log('Config is written');

    // Set reference to mongod in order to close the server during teardown.
    global.MONGOD = mongod;
    process.env.MONGO_URL = mongoConfig.mongoUri;
};
```

Here's the teardown config

```
//teardown.js
module.exports = async function () {
  await global.MONGOD.stop();
};
```

Here's the mongo environment

```
 //mongo-environment.js
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const globalConfigPath = path.join(__dirname, 'globalConfig.json');

module.exports = class MongoEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
    constructor(config) {
        super(config);
    }

    async setup() {
        console.log('Setup MongoDB Test Environment');
        await super.setup();

        const globalConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(globalConfigPath, 'utf-8'));

        this.global.MONGO_URI = globalConfig.mongoUri;
        this.global.MONGO_DB_NAME = globalConfig.mongoDBName;

    }

    async teardown() {
        console.log('Teardown MongoDB Test Environment');
        await super.teardown();
    }

    runScript(script) {
        return super.runScript(script);
    }
};
```

I tried to find help on google but I didn't manage to find any similar issues. I'm hoping someone can shed me some light on this issue.

Thanks